# UiKit iPhone X issue: Blur effect not working

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, iphone-x, uivisualeffectview

I’ve tested a button with uivisualeffectview and it works well. Specifically, I made my custom `UIView` with a blur effect view as its subview . It blurred well with my iPhone 7 and iPad 2018 but when testing with iPhone X, the button became gray and no visual effect appeared. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Is the button located at the very top or very bottom of the screen? If so, maybe it is some issue with auto-layout and the safe-area.

Comment: No it’s in the middle of the screen and the problem is the blur view effect. The shape and position are all right on all devices

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the real reason that causing this issue, in my case i just changed

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to

```
self.show(vc, sender: nil)
```

that fixed the issue, i guess this issue is related with using Custom Views in ViewController